# Why doesn't click work on appended elements?

Tags: jquery, jquery-click-event, jquery-append

I would like to move some html elements from one container to another endlessly using jQuery `append` function but, the click event won't fire no more when I click on the element/s that have been appended.

Based on some threads similar to mine I found out that appended elements are stripped off of their event listeners. How can I avoid that, can someone show a solution ?

Here is the:  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twimB/x2A7n/18/)

```
    $('section.container-A div.elem').click(function() {
        $('section.container-B').append(this) ;
    }) ;

    $('section.container-B div.elem').click(function() {
        $('section.container-A').append(this) ;
    }) ;
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It will work. Use the following method for appended.

```
 $(document).on('click', 'section.container-A div.elem', function() {
        $('section.container-B').append(this) ;
 }) ;
```

Explanation of the problem,

Doing the following,

```
$("span").click(function(){
```

An event handler is attached to all `span` elements that are **currently** on the page, while loading the page. You create new elements with every click. They have no handler attached. You can use

```
$(document).on('click', 'span.class', function(...
```

That will handle the clicks on the new elements as well.

Comment: How to achieve the same results in vanilla js?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the `.on()` method:

```
$(document).on('click', 'section.container-1 div.elem', function() {
    var html = this;
    $('section.container-2').append(html) ;
}) ;

$(document).on('click', 'section.container-2 div.elem', function() {
    var html = this;
    $('section.container-1').append(html) ;
}) ;
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x2A7n/16/

Comment: I used your code, but nothing seems to happen. Is there a particular jQuery version that supports this ON function? I am using 1.9 and above? Thanks

Comment: @twimB My apologies, I've updated my code, forgot `$(document).on()`, along with a fiddle of it working.

Comment: Apparently it doesn't work in Opera. It does work in chrome. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BphGw/1/) and it worked..

Here is the code, hope it helps.

```
$('section.container-1 div.elem').click(function() {     
    var a = $(this).text();     
    $('section.container-2').append('<div class=\'elem\'>' + a + '</div>') ;
}) ;

$('section.container-2 div.elem').click(function() {
    var a = $(this).text();
    $('section.container-1').append('<div  class=\'elem\'>' + a + '</div>') ;
}) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiple div and multiple classes inside your page, it may be trouble to call correct div. 
I found and fixed it via adding the id to the div , and jquery loves find by id and its fast too.  You can use.

```
$(document).on('click touchstart', 'div#the_id div.the_class', function(){
 //yourcode
}
```