# anchor tag refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with anchor tag i fill my html table with append jQuery and inside a td there is anchor tag when i click on it instead of calling it's function it refresh the page:

```js
$('.show-directions').click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.ui.modal').modal('show');
  setTimeout(function() {
    initMap();
  }, 500); 
});

function initMap(){
  console.log("initMap has been called.");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<a class="show-directions" href="">Detail</a>
```

Comment: there is an extra >

Comment: What is `modal()`? Are you using Bootstrap? Have you loaded jQuery?

Comment: it's a window with grey background

Comment: @ScottMarcus I think it damages the post to [fix or change the problem that's being asked about](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code) with an edit.

Comment: @showdev My code does not fix or change the problem. It illuminates the fact that there is a different issue at work here.

Comment: The code works now because you included Bootstrap and jQuery. I suspect that the problem is caused by code that is not shown here; either the `<a>` is added dynamically and the event should be [delegated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) or a library isn't being included. In any case, more information is needed. It doesn't help to make it work with an edit.

Comment: @showdev The OP has indicated that there are no errors in the console, which would not be the case if jQuery and Bootstrap were not referenced.

Comment: Which is why I say I *suspect* and did not post an answer or edit a fix into the question. More information is needed, and I've voted to close as such.

Comment: *The code works now because you included Bootstrap and jQuery.* <-- That statement is false. The OP has these included already and the code does not work.

Comment: That's an assumption; there's no evidence that the OP has included the libraries. And the code does work because you added them, whereas it wasn't working before.

Comment: @showdev No, it's not. The OP has indicated to me in the comments to my answer that this is the case.

Comment: I see no mention of including the libraries.

Comment: @showdev [sigh] *it's not giving me any error*. If one or both libraries were not being linked to properly, there would be an error in the console.

Comment: Since the OPs code throws errors, the statement that there are no errors seems false.

Comment: @showdev *Since the OPs code throws errors* Where does the OP say his code throws errors? He explicitly indicated that it does **not** throw errors.

Comment: The code provided causes errors, including `$ is not defined` because jQuery isn't included and `$(...).modal is not a function`  because Bootstrap is not included. Beyond that, we don't know what else is going on and, in my opinion, we shouldn't assume.

Comment: @showdev Please stop a moment and listen. The OP has already confirmed that jQuery and Bootstrap have been included in his actual code by telling me that he is not getting errors. He simply didn't include those lines in his question. That's why I edited the question and added them. That issue is settled. The problem is not there.

Comment: My disagreement with you does not mean I'm not listening; that's dismissive and rude. I've listened and responded to your points. I'd rather let the problem be defined by the OP, not by your assumptions. There is nobody better to confirm a solution than the OP. Beyond that opinion of mine, it seems we agree that the problem is unclear or can't be reproduced with the code provided.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to the following:

```
$(document).on('click', '.show-directions', function(){ 
   //YourCode
});
```

And it should work.

For an explanation of the problem, read @Optimus Prime answer's here: [Why doesn't click work on appended elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153669/why-doesnt-click-work-on-appended-elements/18153773)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see (after my edit to your question), assuming you have properly referenced the Bootstrap library, your code is working as it should. Your issue therefore must be with something else on the page.

You've indicated that you are dynamically adding the `a` element with `.append()`. In this case, the `click` event handler is being registered before the element has been added to the document. To ensure that it is handled, use **["event delegation"](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**, which is the process of setting up the event handler on a higher level element (that exists at the time of the event registration) in the document and then when the event is later initiated by a lower-level element, event bubbling causes it to arrive at the higher element. You then check to see what element initiated the event.

Having said all of this, **you should not use an `a` for this in the first place.** `<a>` elements are for navigation, not for hooks into JavaScript. It is semantically incorrect to use a hyperlink for non-navigational tasks. It will cause problems for users who use assitive technologies (like screen readers) to surf the web, and (as you already know, given your code) requires you to disable the browser's native desire to navigate by adding `event.preventDefault()`.

Instead use some other element to trigger your function, like a `span` element:

```js
// Intercept the event at the document level, but check to see if
// it originated with an element that has the .show-direcions class
$(document, '.show-directions').click(function( event ) {
  $('.ui.modal').modal('show');
  setTimeout(function() {
    initMap();
  }, 500);
});

function initMap(){
  console.log("initMap has been called.");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<span class="show-directions">Detail</span>
```

Comment: Good advice, but this doesn't really answer the question regarding the OP's current code.

Comment: @showdev The very first sentence of the answer certainly does.

Comment: i tried it but it's the same probleme it doesn't do the call with span

Comment: In my opinion, no. It seems that the OP is trying to use `preventDefault` to prevent the link from being followed, but it's not working.

Comment: @MehdiAmmar As you can see from my solution, it does work as it should. If it's not working for you, you have another, separate issue. Check your developer's console for errors.

Comment: it's not giving me any error i think my only probleme is i am adding the anchor tag by using ajax request and append

Comment: @MehdiAmmar Then, please edit your question to show that code as well.

Answer (score 0):

I did something else

```
<a class="show-directions" href="javascript:tacos();" >
```

and i called the function tacos which has do the same thing

```
function tacos () {
        $('.ui.modal').modal('show');
        setTimeout(function() {

            initMap();
        }, 2000);
    }
```

Comment: While this may "work", it is incorrect in terms of semantics, accessibility and best-practices. JavaScript should not be inline with HTML and `a` elements should not be used for non-navigational tasks. See my updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

Add this in script `$(function(){$("#AnchorTagID").click(function(){return false;});});` or use `<button type='button'>Add Anchor Attributes here<button/>`

Or instead you can add `href="#"` instead of empty href or entirely remove it from there.

Comment: Agreed, just pasted it from a post, updated my answer as well

Comment: Your answer still uses inline JavaScript.

Comment: Ok, but now your answer just does what the OP is already doing with `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Edited again, I hope this satisfies the question.

Comment: Sorry, but you're stuck on providing an answer that is not relevant to the problem. The problem isn't cancelling the anchor click. The problem is that the anchor is not getting the click event handler registered properly. Your answer has nothing to do with the problem.